# What are the differences between the two cases?

Tags: ruby

I want to know the difference between two cases:

```
module M
# def self.append_features(base) 
#   if base < self then p true
#   else                p false
#   end
# end
end

class C
  include M
end

if C < M then p true
else          p false
end
```

The output is:

```
true
```

But if I remove the comments, the output is:

```
false
false
```

Why is the output different from the previous output?

Comment: I don't think that code does what you think it does. Comparing constants like that makes no sense.

Comment: There's the [`<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-3C) method to test if a module is a subclass of another, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,It isn't comparing constants,checking if class C is subclass of M.

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, but what are your 2 cases? How does the out commented code like to the example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's have a look at the C level of `Module#append_features`

```
static VALUE
rb_mod_append_features(VALUE module, VALUE include)
{
    if (!CLASS_OR_MODULE_P(include)) {
        Check_Type(include, T_CLASS);
    }
    rb_include_module(include, module);

    return module;
}
```

The first parameter `module` is the module to be included, and the second parameter `include` is the module or class that include `module`, a.k.a. `base`.

You can see a function call `rb_include_module(include, module)`. That function handles adding methods and constants of `module` into `include`.

So if you overrided `Module#append_features`, and you forgot to call `super` in it, then the module will never be actually included.

You may never want to override `Module#append_features`. If you want to attach some "listener" to the "event" when a module is included, you can override `Module#included`. By default this method does nothing.